# English grammar is not (so difficult/very difficult/too difficult/difficult enough) to understand

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

I can't decide which is the right option to choose. I can say that 'difficult enough' is not the right option, because it doesn't make much sense. But, so difficult/too difficult/very difficult look all the same to me.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Will "difficultly enough" be correct?

Comment: @Boyep ----- NO.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't agree with your first comment. If we read 'difficult to understand' as a phrase, it can be qualified by _so_ or _very_.

Comment: I agree with Kate Bunting. You could also say it "*is easy enough* to understand."

Comment: As the OP says, _difficult enough_ doesn't make sense in his sentence. You could say something like "Climbing a mountain is difficult enough in good weather. In a snowstorm it would be impossible." (Here, the gerund _climbing_ acts like a noun.)

Comment: @KateBunting I just don't understand why it doesn't make sense, is it because it is related to verb "understand" and therefore it's not correct? Is there some rule?

Comment: @Boyep "English grammar is not difficult enough to understand" sounds as though you needed it to be _more_ difficult in order to understand it! It's the opposite of "too difficult to understand".

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. Can you answer me please, if it’s not difficult for you, is the second answer correct?: quora.com/Is-funnily-enough-more-correct-than-funny-enough

Comment: @Boyep I don't understand what you mean by 'the second answer'.